# converting ARGB to RGB in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, hex

I have created a variable using System.Windows.Media.Color.

I can display the Hex value from this variable using ToString(); however that also gives me the alpha value.  Is there anyway to get just the RGB values out?  If I try using Color.R.ToString(); it only gives me the numerical value.

Do I have to change it to hex manually or is there a built in method for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I gather from your question you want to convert it to a hex-format color. You can just individually convert each of the color's members, leaving out the alpha:

```
string color_str = string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", Color.R, Color.G, Color.B);
```

Comment: I came to find the code snippet returning "#2X2X2X" while passing Color.Red

Comment: @AbrahamJP: oops, that's what I get for not testing my code. It's X2, not 2X. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I came to find the "ColorTranslator" also doing the Color to Hex conversion in a more concise manner.

```
 Color C = Color.Red;
 string HexVal = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(C.R, C.G, C.B)));
```